# Adding images to json search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, image

I have created a search bar using ajax and json which works however im having difficulty adding images, anytime i try to add an image it stops the search functionality. This is the code where im trying to add an image:

```
  output +='<img src="images/' + val.imageref +'" />';
```

and this is a snippit of some of the code from the json file:

```
[{
"brand": "Pedigree",
"product": "Dentastix Fresh",
"type": "Food",
"imageref": "images/dentastix.jpg",
"price": "£5.00"
}, {
"brand": "Trixie",
"product": "Automatic Food Dispenser Tx2",
"type": "Food bowl",
"imageref": "images/dogbowl.jpg",
"price": "£10.00"
```

does anyone have any suggestions how i can add images in?

entire code:

```
   <label for="search">Search <a href="#"><img src="images/search.jpg"></a></label><input type="search" name="search" class="tool" title="Type in a product name or category to get started" id="search" placeholder="Product..." />


                </div>
      <div id="update"></div>
      <script>
     $('#search').keyup(function(){
      var searchField = $('#search').val();
     var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
     $.getJSON('search.json', function(data){
      var output = '<ul class="searchresult">';
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        if((val.brand.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.type.search(myExp) != -1)) {
          output +='<h1>' + val.brand + '</h1>';
          output +='<h2>' + val.product + '</h2>';
          output +='<img src="images/' + val.type +'/'+ val.brand + val.product + '.jpg" />';
          output +='<p>' + val.price +  '</p>';
          output +='</li>';
        }
      });
      output += '</ul>';
      $('#update').html(output);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: you are apparently duplicating `images/`. In a nutshell, your tag is looking for an image located in `images/images/`. Is this intended or..? (because it concatenates `images/` with `images/dentastix.jpg` for the first case, as an example)

Comment: if possible create fiddle...

Comment: hi there when ive edited the question above to include the entire code, if you could look at it that would be very helpful.

Comment: Also at the minute if i take part of the image line away it stops the search working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're duplicating your images directory when you reference the path in your output variable. Unless images/images/dogbowl.jpg is where your image is. You might try using a hosted image to test to make sure it's not a file path issue.

Could you include a code sample on codepen or another service with more details?

Comment: hi @Hoffination i edited the question about to include all the code, if you could look at it that would be very helpful